# What is the window size on Questions Per Day average for this site?

Tags: discussion, beta

I have a question about the number of questions per day shown on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel). I expect it is some kind of [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average). What is the window size of this average?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mouse over the big number in the blue box, then the mouse tip title will tell you! Currently, it reads

```
7.5 questions per day on average over the past two weeks
```

From which we learn that it's averaged over the figures for the past 2 weeks. I think that's a rolling 14 day average, calculated roughly daily, but the very exact details probably don't matter too much!

Answer (score 5):

According to a comment on [this thread](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/chart-for-visits-per-day), it's a two week moving average, but I don't know where he gets his source.

*edit* we have similar stats available to us as mods, and our one is a one-week moving average...